# Wildfly 8.0.0 mysql problems with datasource

Tags: mysql, eclipse, wildfly

I've got a small problem with my standalone.xml. I made an order mysql in `modules/system/layers/base/com`.
 Inside this folder there is the folder main and inside that there is my `mysql-Connector v.5.1.28` and the module.xml.

But when I run a project in Eclipse it doesn't open up the browser.If I open it in the Safari browser than the textfields are shown but the whole database entries, which should be shown up too, are missing. Instead it throws an `ClassNotFoundExeption` for the mysql driver. Here the snippet of my standalone.xml:

```
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>sa</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDB" pool-name="MyDB" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>root</user-name>
      <password>root</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
      <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
      <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
      <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
      <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Can anyone see the problem?

the path is modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main...inside is the mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar..the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
<resources>

    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem and removing this part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuraton:

$WILDFLY_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main/mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar.

And in $WILDFLY_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main/module.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
      <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
      <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
      <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
  </module>
```

And in $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml:

```
<drivers>
  ...
  <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
  ...
</drivers>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is wonderful guide here.
http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/

Follow this and you should be good in setting it up.

Take care of one point (blunder which I did)

While creating the module.xml on windows system see to it you save the file with proper extension.
Check the type on windows explorer, it should not be a Text Document but XML Document.

To be on safer side enable the following :

Organize --> Folder and Search Option -->View Tab -->(UnCheck the option : Hide extensions for known file types)

So file you end up creating should not be **modudle.xml.txt** but  **module.xml**

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If people are trying to integrate this version mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 please don't waste time just use the below version. I am leaving this cause I was finding the details but could find much detail on the the version which failed work i.e. " mysql-connector-java-5.0.8"

Please download the latest version mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 it will work for the Wild fly deployment . I believe there is a defect with the earlier version of the mysql driver and they fixed the issue in the latest version. I believe it sees the compliance check which probably not loading the classes .

Check more on this url 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62038

configuration above are right it is just that driver has the issue. please don't try and waste time just download the latest one.