# wildfly registering mysql as a datasource

Tags: mysql, wildfly-8

I have been trying to configure mysql as a datasource in wildfly. I am not sure what i am missing out, i get an error on startup .

I have the  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and the  module.xml in the folder: 
"/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main"

below are the files

module.xml

```
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" 
        name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

standalone.xml

```
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>sa</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/proj" pool-name="proj" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>root</user-name>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
      <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
      <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
      <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
      <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I have tested the jdbc connectivity with a standalone program in eclipse and it worked

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ConnectSql {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String userName = "root";
        String pass = "admin123";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
        String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String db = "proj";

        try{
            //registering the driver.
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,userName,pass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select f_name from t_users");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("name :"+rs.getString(1));
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
            cnf.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Referred to the below link and modified the module.xml

[Wildfly 8.0.0 mysql problems with datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120130/wildfly-8-0-0-mysql-problems-with-datasource)

Here is a the error log i get on start up

> 02:45:17,169 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed -
>   address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("data-source" => "proj") ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>       "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/proj is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
>       "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/proj is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]" ]} 02:45:17,175 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("data-source" => "proj") ]) - failure description: {
>       "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/proj is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
>           "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/proj is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
>       ],
>       "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>           "Services that were unable to start:" => [
>               "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.proj",
>               "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.proj"
>           ],
>           "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"]
>       } }

Answer (score 5):

To resolve the mysql datasource configuration issue on Wildfly i used the admin console  to add the datasource and test it.

1. If you login to the web console and find the datasource you tried configuring disable
     that a remove it . The standalone.xml and the module.xml get reset to the orginal.

   [Steps for accessing web console](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Admin+Guide?_sscc=t#AdminGuide-Accessingthewebconsole)
2. Configure a new datasource :

   name :mysql 
   JNDI :java:jboss/datasources/proj
3. Click next and enter the url (i used the below) and click enable and then click test
   url : jdbc:mysql://localhost/proj
4. The test should show success
5. The changes to the standalone.xml and the module.xml are automatically made .
6. If you restart the server now it should start without any errors and you should be able to access the database from your web project

Answer (score 2):

I have working configuration of mysql driver on wildfly.

```
       <datasources>
            // ...
            <drivers>
                // ...
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

The little difference seems to be presence of "driver-class" tag.

I hope it will help.

(Deploying mysql driver as a deployment also works and it's recommended way. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration )

**[edit]**

I have mysql module under wildfly/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main/ . I've noticed just now you module path doesn't correspond to module name. And I haven't find any doc's just yet, but I don't think you should mess with modules/system directory.

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql.jdbc">    
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Tried adding the <driver-class> tags in the standalone.xml . I still get the same error

Comment: You can try using newer version of mysql driver. I'm using 5.1.30 . Also, what os are you using? My colleagues at work run into some issues on Windows with version wildfly-8.1.0.Final (I don't know the details). They ended up downgrading to Wildfly-8.0.0.Final .

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 .I tried updating the driver still get the same error

Comment: I forgot to mention that have moved the  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar to the path /wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main"  after reading the instruction in the below link https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide.           I updated the path details in the question . Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

Two things: I just got mine working, and have the driver and xml located in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main - I'm fairly new with this as well so I'm not sure if that matters. Another thing: I don't know if it is just a typo, but if it was just copied and pasted it looks like your JAR name is incorrect

```
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar"/>
```

when it should be

```
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
```

I forgot the .jar in mine, and that ended up fixing it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you download the mysql connector zip and uploading the zip as a deployment. But the correct way is to unzip your download and point to the contained jar.

Answer (score 0):

There are [three ways](http://pvrworld-wildfly.blogspot.in/2016/11/getting-started-guide-wildfly.html) using which you can simply create datasource into wildfly

1. Using admin console
2. Manually adding into standalone.xml
3. Creating datasource file that is xml file.

Go to **WildFly directory/standalone/deployments**
Simplest way to create datasource xml with following content

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
      <datasource jndi-name="APP_DS" pool-name="APP_DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <driver>mysql</driver>

        <!-- sql to call when connection is created -->
        <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>

        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
        </pool>

        <security>
          <user-name>username</user-name>
          <password>password</password>
        </security>

        <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool -->
        <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        </validation>

        <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>300000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
        <track-statements>true</track-statements>
        </statement>      
      </datasource>
    </datasources>
```